How to separate dependency configuration from UI project of an ASP.NET Core Blazor Web App?
I have a Blazor Web App with the Server hosting model in .NET 8 with the WebApplication.CreateBuilder minimal hosting model.
In the solution I use multiple library projects to foster a clean architecture throughout the application, most notably I control exactly how projects reference each other. This way it is technically not possible that, for example, the domain model project accidentally references a type from the persistence (database) project.
As with every default Blazor app, this Blazor project currently does two things:

Configuring the dependency injection of the whole app
Hosting the UI components

The first point causes the Blazor project to reference each other project of the solution. Which leads to the possibility that any UI component now can reference a type from, for example, the persistence project. My goal is to prevent that so that the Blazor components can only know about types in projects with interfaces for the UI.
Since configuring dependencies for injection has to be done very early in the hosting startup process, my idea was to create a dedicated project for the hosting which is allowed to know any other project to configure the dependency injection. Which means that the builder.Services.Add(...) part for my custom types wouldn't be in the Blazor project anymore.
How can I achieve that?
The hosting project surely needs some kind of Program.cs, optimally using top-level statements without the class Program boilerplate. But does it make sense to use WebApplication.CreateBuilder there? This seems to create trouble since the hosting project then must be of type <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"> and then the default behavior for ContentRootPath/WebRootPath doesn't work, since they are looked for in the hosting project, while actually being in the Blazor project. And maybe other problems exist too, which I haven't discovered yet.
I've created a minimal sample project which shows the problem with the webroot folder if I go that way: https://github.com/Megadesty/blazor-host-dependency-example

You can create static classes with extension methods to extend IServiceCollection in the different libraries.
Here's an example one from one of my Demo projects that defines the Clean Design Infrastructure services.
public static class ApplicationInfrastructureServices
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the server side Mapped Infrastructure services
    /// and generic handlers
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services"></param>
    public static void AddAppServerMappedInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContextFactory<InMemoryTestDbContext>(options
            => options.UseInMemoryDatabase($"TestDatabase-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}"));

        services.AddScoped<IDataBroker, DataBroker>();

        // Add the standard handlers
        services.AddScoped<IListRequestHandler, ListRequestServerHandler<InMemoryTestDbContext>>();
        services.AddScoped<IItemRequestHandler, ItemRequestServerHandler<InMemoryTestDbContext>>();
        services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler, CommandServerHandler<InMemoryTestDbContext>>();

        // Add any individual entity services
        services.AddMappedWeatherForecastServerInfrastructureServices();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the generic services for the API Data Pipeline infrastructure
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services"></param>
    /// <param name="baseHostEnvironmentAddress"></param>
    public static void AddAppClientMappedInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services, string baseHostEnvironmentAddress)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddHttpClient(AppDictionary.Common.WeatherHttpClient, client => { client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseHostEnvironmentAddress); });

        services.AddScoped<IDataBroker, DataBroker>();

        services.AddScoped<IListRequestHandler, ListRequestAPIHandler>();
        services.AddScoped<IItemRequestHandler, ItemRequestAPIHandler>();
        services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler, CommandAPIHandler>();

        services.AddAppClientMappedWeatherForecastInfrastructureServices();
    }

This is consumed in the deployment project - such as a Blazor server project.
You can see the full Repo where this comes from here:
https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo/tree/Next
And one of the solutions:
https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo/tree/Next/Source/Applications/Blazr.Weather
Part 2 Shared wwwroot
In the provided Repo you can set up the app.razor in the UI project as follows:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <base href="/"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Ui/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Ui/app.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Ui/Ui.bundle.scp.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="_content/Ui/favicon.png"/>
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer"/>
</head>

<body>
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer"/>
<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

This does highlight one problem in isolated Css files in libraries.  Normally these would be bundled into the server project css.  But in the library you don't know what the deployment server project is [there may be more than one], so you need to reference all the libraries that provide isolated Css files separately.
You can also use a FileProvider with UseStaticFile. See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Thanks for your suggestion, this is indeed very useful and cleans up the code. In fact, I'm already doing this. But it actually doesn't solve my problem, since the Blazor server project still needs to reference all other projects to call these IServiceCollection extension methods, which means that the components can reference bad stuff. But your repo gave me another hint: When I create a Razor lib and move all files from the Blazor host project to that lib, except appsettings, Program.cs and webroot folder, then it works.

It would be cleaner if the webroot folder also could live inside the Razor lib, but I didn't manage to get that working yet. Otherwise, it works, so thanks for the tip!

I've created a minimal sample project to show where the problem with the webroot folder is. Just in case you have an idea :) https://github.com/Megadesty/blazor-host-dependency-example

I'm very careful now to separate the components into a Razor Library.  They have no access to the Infrastructure and other back end projects.   The server [or WASM] project - what I call a Deployment - contains the bare minimum and has to access the backend projects to populate DI.   Will take a look at your repo.

See my addition to the answer on dealing with webroots.

Awesome, it works! Turns out I searched the internet with the wrong keywords, since my final problem didn't have anything to do with the project structure - I was already on the right track with that. But I was missing the _content part in the links. Thanks alot Shaun! I also updated my repo, in case someone else stumbles upon this.

NP.  Glad to be of assistance and my Blazr.Demo repo was helpful.  That's what it's there for!

As a further thankyou I've just donated to the German cancer aid group. Just as you have wished in your repo!
